# pass value within one form in ms-access

Tags: vba, ms-access

hey i am a total noob and only found ways to pass a value between two forms.
this is the form i am working with: [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTuRr.png).
in this form (event.form) there is a subform (Fundort_kurz-Subform) which lists data. when i click one row inside the subform the value for "objid" appears in textbox "text501" by "=[Fundort_kurz-Subform].[Form]![Objid]". I automatically want the value from field "text501" to be passed to field "Objid_3" which is meant to write the value into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing, but use the *OnCurrent* event of the subform:

```
Me.Parent!Objid_3.Value = Me!text501.Value
```

And do rename your controls to something meaningful.